# ECheck payment via PayPal API

Tags: php, paypal

I'm working on PayPal Payments Pro (Direct Payment) and have covered several of its operations like DoDirectPayment, DoCaputure, DoAuthorization,CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile and etc as per this below article.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/#id5ba04ce4-aa8e-4586-99b5-609f59141f56

I'm looking for way to allow user to pay via ECheck? I very well know how Authorize.net AIM interface offers to pay via Echeck method but I don't see the Echeck method in Direct Payment for PayPal.

Can someone point me to something helpful? Thanks

Comment: The user always has the option of paying with an echeck if I'm not mistaken. It's up to you to not complete and fulfill the order until the postback comes in showing the payment has cleared fully though. They send said postback the same method as regular payments.